# Using python to query keywords in a arcmap layer

Tags: python, arcmap

I currently have a data set of latitude and longitude points plotted in ArcMap. These coordinates were imported from excel and have a "notes" column. I was wondering if there was any way to query select words from this column to change the symbol on the map.

I am not well versed in python but my attempted logic is as follows:

```
def FindKeyWord ([Notes]):
   if Notes.str.contains("Detrital zircon")]:
       return (symbol as a black triangle)
   else:
       return (symbol as a black circle)
```

I hope what I am attempting to accomplish makes sense. I might have to just make a whole new spreadsheet for the rows with the attribute and have two separate layers.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the `symbol` part but you can query your data easily with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file')

mask = df['notes'].str.contains('Detrital zircon')
black_traingle = df[mask]
black_circle = df[~mask]
```